# NoMachine on Linux cannot connect to Windows 11 Home

Tags: linux, windows, nomachine

I've installed the latest NoMachine on my Win11 Home edition.  Win11 can connect to my Linux laptop but when I try to connect from Linux to Win11 NoMachine just spins.

Any ideas?

Comment: To connect from Windows to Linux, install and configure Samba on the Linux machine.  To connect from Linux to Windows:   smb://ipofwindows/folder.

Comment: @John What does Samba/smb has to do with NoMachine / remote desktop?

Comment: I assume @OP wants to connect them.  What I described is for regular Linux and Windows connections